# How do I set the password that contains quotation mark to a connection string in an ASP.NET application?

Tags: database, asp.net, connection

How do I set the password that contains quotation mark to a connection string in an ASP.NET application?

**Answer:**

Password: This"Is"Password

In connection string: This""Is""Password

Comment: Make your life easier by changing that password.

Answer (score 0):

Great resource for [Connection Strings](http://connectionstrings.com/)

Answer (score 0):

Encode it as a

```
      &quot;
```

That's how " are encoded in XML.

Let me know if it works :-)

Here is a link.

http://xml.silmaril.ie/authors/specials/